# Pausing a VBA loop to allow editing of worksheet, with or without userform

Tags: vba, excel, userform

I have a procedure that consists of several `do` and `for` loops and i would like to find an easy way to 'pause' the routine and allow the user to edit the sheet, with a msgbox or userform to resume execution where it left off.

I would like to do something like this

```
dim pause as boolean
pause=false
For i = 1 To 40
    Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A" & i) = i
    If i = 20 Then
        UserForm1.Show vbmodeless
          Pause = true
        Do until pause = false
        loop
    Else

    End If
    Next i


End Sub
```

Where the pause condition would be set by a sub on the userform. This do loop just crashes.

**Ideally** i would like the userform to have buttons that can run subs but also allow direct editing of cells while execution is paused.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a typical control structure that allows the user to perform some actions in the middle of a macro.  When the user is done, they run **OKToContinue** to allow the macro to continue with the second part:

```
Dim AllowedToContinue As Boolean

Sub FirstPartSecondPart()
    AllowedToContinue = False
    MsgBox "allow user to perform actions"
    Do Until AllowedToContinue
        DoEvents
    Loop
    MsgBox "doing second part"
End Sub

Sub OKToContinuw()
    AllowedToContinue = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Remember to declare your boolean value as `global` if more than 1 sub is sharing it! thank you